# imageview not displaying image from URL

Tags: android

I need to fetch the image from the URL http://blogs.fco.gov.uk/peterbeckingham/files/2012/08/goa-beach.jpg
which is pretty much accessible. Here is my piece of code ,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView templateImage;
Bitmap bm;
String templateImageURL;
byte[] binaryURL=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        templateImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.templateImage);
        templateImageURL="http://blogs.fco.gov.uk/peterbeckingham/files/2012/08/goa-beach.jpg";
        DownloadImageTask dwnloadtask=new DownloadImageTask();
        dwnloadtask.execute();
    }

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         Drawable image;
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
              image = ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(), templateImageURL, "image.jpg");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             templateImage.setImageDrawable(image);
        }
        private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                return d;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
         public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                Object content = url.getContent();
                return content;
            }
    }
```

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/templateImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imageurldemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the exception im getting, though the file is available

```
10-04 11:00:10.394: W/System.err(17887): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://blogs.fco.gov.uk/peterbeckingham/files/2012/08/goa-beach.jpg
10-04 11:00:10.394: W/System.err(17887):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-04 11:00:10.394: W/System.err(17887):    at java.net.URLConnection$DefaultContentHandler.getContent(URLConnection.java:1018)
10-04 11:00:10.394: W/System.err(17887):    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:199)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.fetch(MainActivity.java:105)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.ImageOperations(MainActivity.java:91)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:111)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-04 11:00:10.399: W/System.err(17887):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: are u trying to display this image in ur imageview which is showing null?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing this kind lengthy process? When Android has given us a good things to work with. See below my answer it will very useful and compaq to work with.

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that jar file from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

```
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading; getting a bitmap, if needed; etc.

Comment: I have also tried this 
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

  androidAQuery.id(templateImage).image("http://preston.lib.mn.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/teddy-bear.gif", true, true, 500, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 but no use, the launcher image is being displayed

Comment: Please give your complete url with http you url is wrong in aQuery syntax.

Comment: AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);androidAQuery.id(templateImage).image("http://preston.lib.mn.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/teddy-bear.gif", true, true, 500, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Comment: I have entered http, but stackoverflow is not displaying it

Comment: Dont put it in background. Put it outside and check your syntax again. Its working like charm just check once proper.

Comment: @pratt in my baseadapter class i used aquery to load image..but it shows ic_launcher image..

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to download image from url.

> ```
>   // DownloadImage AsyncTask
>     private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
>      @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         // Create a progressdialog
>         mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
>         // Set progressdialog title
>         mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image.... ");
>         // Set progressdialog message
>         mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
>         mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         // Show progressdialog
>         mProgressDialog.show();
>     }
>      @Override
>     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {
>          String imageURL = URL[0];
>          Bitmap bitmap = null;
>         try {
>             // Download Image from URL
>             InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
>             // Decode Bitmap
>             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return bitmap;
>     }
>      @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
>         // Set the bitmap into ImageView
>         image.setImageBitmap(result);
>         // Close progressdialog
>         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
>     }
>       }
>   }
> ```

Use the above code as below:

> ```
>       templateImageURL="http://blogs.fco.gov.uk/peterbeckingham/files/2012/08/goa-beach.jpg";
>         // Execute DownloadImage AsyncTask
>         new DownloadImage().execute(templateImageURL);
> ```

Also In order to load images from an url we first need to store the image in a temporary location and once it is downloaded it should be added to `ImageView`. To create a temporary file we need to access device external storage. Add required permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` file . There is not need of `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

```
   To access external storage required permission is – WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: still the same 10-04 11:16:06.059: W/System.err(19181): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://blogs.fco.gov.uk/peterbeckingham/files/2012/08/goa-beach.jpg
10-04 11:16:06.059: W/System.err(19181):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-04 11:16:06.059: W/System.err(19181):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
10-04 11:16:06.059: W/System.err(19181):  at com.example.imageurldemo.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)

Comment: Yes I did the same , I have also added the permission in manifest